# Why does passing variables to subprocess.Popen not work despite passing a list of arguments?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script which calls another Python script by `subprocess.Popen`. But since I have arguments stored in variable(s)

```
servers[server]['address']
servers[server]['port']
servers[server]['pass']
```

I am unable to perform the command

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["python mytool.py -a ", servers[server]['address'], "-x", servers[server]['port'], "-p", servers[server]['pass'], "some additional command"],
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Comment: Use the variables to build a string that is the command, or pass them as a list of arguments.

Comment: Calling Python as a subprocess of Python is an antipattern unto itself; a better solution is usually to refactor the script from the subprocess so you can `import` it and call it directly from the parent script. There _are_ situations where you genuinely want a subprocess (for example, if the script uses signals which you need to handle differently in the parent) but more often than not, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: As a further aside, as already pointed out in the `subprocess` documentation, you should avoid `Popen` if your use case is already handled by one of the higher-level functions `subprocess.run()` and friends. Basically, unless you require parallel processing or interaction with the running process, don't use `Popen` (and if you do, take care of waiting for the child process etc which `Popen` does not do for you).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Drop `shell=True`. [The arguments to `Popen()` are treated differently on Unix if `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137299/4279):

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# populate list of arguments
args = ["mytool.py"]
for opt, optname in zip("-a -x -p".split(), "address port pass".split()):
    args.extend([opt, str(servers[server][optname])])
args.extend("some additional command".split())

# run script
p = Popen([sys.executable or 'python'] + args, stdout=PIPE)
# use p.stdout here...
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

Note that passing `shell=True` for commands with external input is a security hazard, as described by a warning [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Answer (score 13):

When you call `subprocess.Popen` you can pass either a string or a list for the command to be run. If you pass a list, the items should be split in a particular way.

In your case, you need to split it something like this:

```
command = ["python",  "mytool.py", "-a", servers[server]['address'], 
           "-x", servers[server]['port'], 
           "-p", servers[server]['pass'], 
           "some",  "additional", "command"]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This is because if you pass in a list, `Popen` assumes you have already split the command line into words (the values that would end up in `sys.argv`), so it doesn't need to.

The way you're calling it, it will try to run a binary called "python mytool.py -a", which isn't what you meant.

The other way to fix it is to join all of the words into a string (which `Popen` will then split up - see [`subprocess.list2cmdline`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/90d4153728f6/Lib/subprocess.py#l622)). But you're better off using the list version if possible - it gives simpler control of how the commandline is split up (if arguments have spaces or quotes in them, for example) without having to mess around with quoting quote characters.

Comment: The variable I use to store the output, but on print it's empty (which I guess hasn't been executed).

Comment: I think you mean that when you read from p.stdout, there's no output? That will be because the command is not being run.

Comment: Actually, the shell=True is probably muddying the water here - unless you're using globbing (to expand out a list of files, say), it's best to turn it off.

Comment: without shell=true, the script refuses to execute, it shows "sh: mytool.sh command not found"

Comment: Put in the full path to mytool.sh - whatever "which mytool.sh" gives when you type it on the commandline.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem in type `str` for first `Popen` argument. Replace it to `list`. Below code can work:

```
address = servers[server]['address']
port = servers[server]['port']
pass = servers[server]['pass']

command = "python mytool.py -a %s -x %d -p %s some additional command" % (address, port, pass)
p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#        it is a list^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  shell=False
```

If `command` arguments get from a trusted source you can construct `command` and use it with `shell=True` to such manner:

```
import pipes as p
command = "python mytool.py -a {} -x {} -p {} some additional command".format(p.quote(address), p.quote(port), p.quote(pass))
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**Note 1**: constructed `command` with `shell=True`is potentially insecure. Use `pipes.quote()` for reduce injection possibility.
**Note 2**: `pipes.quote()` deprecated since `python2`; for `python3` use `shlex` module.

Comment: Had the similar issue as before, but I resolved it now. Thanks :)

Comment: If you pass a list with `shell=True`, the first argument is treated as a shell script, and subsequent arguments as parameters for that script (its `$0`, `$1`, etc). The results of this `shlex.split()` operation isn't a list intended to be parsed that way; in practice, it will run `python` with no arguments.

Comment: Much improved as to the first half. Re: the second half, better to demonstrate use of `pipes.quote()` (or in Python 3 `shlex.quote()`) for creating content that *can* be substituted into a shell command safely, rather than just putting in unsafe code with a bunch of caveats.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Updated Now I can't check the last update. Please review it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate the command to a whole string:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("python mytool.py -a " + servers[server]['address'] + " -x " + servers[server]['port'] + " -p " + servers[server]['pass'] + " some additional command", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: I have the output saved to variable but there's no output or trace of the script being executed. may be direct error output to check it?

Comment: Add "stderr=subprocess.PIPE" also

Comment: If someone feeds you a list of addresses that contains `$(rm -rf ~)`, you'd better hope nobody is using this concatenation-based approach. This is massively insecure; even if you *do* want to use `shell=True`, the (only) safe way to do it is to pass variables out-of-band from script code: `p = subprocess.Popen(['python mytool.py -a "$1" -x "$2" -p "$3" some additional command', '_', str(servers[server]['address']), str(servers[server]['port']), str(servers[server]['pass'])], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment by passing

```
env={whatever_you_want: values} | os.environ
```

in your subprocess call.

Answer (score -1):

Usecase

To run n amount of shell script or python script

Create a run.py file that responsible to pass the argument(integer) to the shell file.

Let say you like to run n(4) qty of shell script or python script that accept **1** argument.

Create a file **run.python** with the code below.

Below code illustrate

- instanceQty = Amount of shell script to run
- os.getcwd() = path to your current file
- mockScript.sh = **shell script** that I put on same directory with **run.py**

To run shell script

```
# this is python file with name run.py
import subprocess,os
instanceQty = 4
for i in range(0, instanceQty):
    print(os.getcwd())
    subprocess.Popen(f"{os.getcwd()}/mockScript.sh {i}",shell=True,executable='/bin/bash')
```

To run python script

```
import subprocess,os,sys
instanceQty = 4
for i in range(0, instanceQty):
    print(os.getcwd())
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,f"{os.getcwd()}/mockScript.py",str(i)])
```

Run this file with

> python run.py

permission problem on MacOS

> sudo chmod ug+x mockScript.sh

> sudo chmod ug+x run.py

**All code tested on Python 3.8.1 and MacOs 12.0.1 environment.**

Comment: The call to `os.getcwd()` is completely unnecessary here; see [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: The "permission problem" also seems like a beginner misunderstanding. If you explicitly run `python script.py` you only need read access to `script.py` (though for convenience in interactive use, you probably want the script to have a shebang and be marked executable too).