# Remove quotation marks from a ping in CMD (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple ping (ping target.com) in a terminal.

The problem is the terminal counts the quotation marks in the string `"ping"`. The result of my code now will be:

`""ping target.com""` and this will run a error --> `""ping target.com"" is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I know that problem is the double mark but I don´t know how to remove the quotation mark from the ping.

Here the code:

```
target = input('[+] Please put the IP target: ')


ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping " + target], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = ping.communicate()[0] #access stdoutdata
print(out)
```

Comment: [how to user subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python)  , use `ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping ", target], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Hi @ sahasrara62 I tried it but it still doesn't work

Comment: [passing-variables-to-subprocess-popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140137/passing-variables-to-subprocess-popen) use `ping = subprocess.Popen(f"ping {target}",shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` if you want to use `shell=true` else use `ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", target],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Thank you dude! Is working! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues.  When passing a command to [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), the documentation says this for ushing `shell=True`:

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Also, you're printing the output of the `communicate` call, which is a byte array.  You probably want to decode it, so it's looks correct to the user:

```
import subprocess
target = input('[+] Please put the IP target: ')
# Just pass a normal string to Popen
ping = subprocess.Popen("ping " + target, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = ping.communicate()[0] #access stdoutdata
# Decode the output to a normal string
print(out.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ["ping", target]

Comment: I also tried it but it still doesn't work

Comment: too big of a hurry. I should have tested it first. Nothing is true if you do not test it. :)