# Run process with keyword arguments using python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, arguments

**More Generally:** How can I run a process that runs from the terminal with required keyword arguments using python?

It seems subprocess.Popen is what I want to use.

Here is what I try to run from inside a script:

```py
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(['goodreads-user-scraper', '--user_id 149832357'])
```

“goodreads-user-scraper” is recognized, but I don’t understand how to pass a keyword argument. I know how to pass an argument, but if I remove “—user_id” I still get same problem.
[image]

I have installed goodreads-user-scraper. It works well from the terminal. It is a python package that you can run from the terminal. Repository found [here](https://github.com/YashTotale/goodreads-user-scraper).

Below is how I would ideally like to run the process but from inside python:

```bash
pip install goodreads-user-scraper
goodreads-user-scraper --user_id <your id> --output_dir goodreads-data
```

Result of running from terminal:
[image]

### Research

In my research I have found these two that seem helpful, but I haven’t been able to adapt the answers to my needs:

- [Why does passing variables to subprocess.Popen not work despite passing a list of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140137/why-does-passing-variables-to-subprocess-popen-not-work-despite-passing-a-list-o)
- [How to use subprocess popen Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate all of your arguments like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(['goodreads-user-scraper', '--user_id', '149832357'])
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried this, but maybe I didn't pay close attention. It's working now for sure. Thanks!